# Azure app service deployed app not changed request URL

Tags: angular, .net-core, azure-appservice

I have deployed a .net core(3.1) + Angular(11) application to Azure app service. It is working perfectly in local environment with IIS and application loads the when I type the URL. But when try to send a request, the request URL is still remains the same like IIS.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXuwf.png)

This environment.dev.ts file should be used in the runtime

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    environment: 'Development',
    clientAppUrl: 'https://aaaaa.azurewebsites.net',
    baseUrl: 'https://aaaa.azurewebsites.net/api/'
};
```

Comment: Your image says the request is going to `localhost:44360` -- that doesn't seem like the correct URL. Where is that url coming from? (I.e. is it hardcoded in your angular code?)

Comment: I have kept a separate environment file as environment.dev.ts. But it was not detected by the runtime I guess. Please see the update question.